# targeting a class of a css id

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to target the class .page-has-children in the following code:

```
<div id="dc_jqverticalmegamenu_widget-2" class="widget sidebarwidget ">
  <div class="dcjq-vertical-mega-menu" id="dc_jqverticalmegamenu_widget-2-item">
    <ul id="menu-media-intellectual-property" class="menu">
      <li id="menu-item-2674" class="page-has-children menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2674">
        <a href="http://saracens.staging.wpengine.com/commercial-clients/commercial-litigation/media-and-intellectual-property">Media and Intellectual Property</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-2672" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2672">
              <a href="http://saracens.staging.wpengine.com/commercial-clients/commercial-litigation/media-and-intellectual-property/it-and-software-disputes">IT and Software Disputes</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-2673" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2673">
              <a href="http://saracens.staging.wpengine.com/private-clients/civil-litigation/media-and-intellectual-property/trademarks-and-patents">Trademarks and Patents</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>     
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried multiple variations, but i was pretty sure this one should work:

```
#dc_jqverticalmegamenu_widget-%ID%-item li.page-has-children  {}
```

I've also tried

```
div.dcjq-vertical-mega-menu li.page-has-children {
  background: url(images/arrow-right.gif) no-repeat -3px 0px;
  padding: 0 0 0 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

I've also tried recommendations from this forum post: http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/10960/target-a-class-inside-id/p1

None of them allow me to see the arrow on a menu item that has children.

Comment: Suggest: temporarily add `background-color: red` to the selector to make it very clear if it is working (easier to know it worked than more subtle properties) and then also use FireBug, IE/Chrome development tools to check if the selector is matching. As id's are unique having multiple id selectors in an selector is pointless (or do you have non-unique ids?)

Comment: Also suggest starting with some vastly simplified (especially when asking questions): even with code clean up someone (or some-CMS?) seems to want to stress test the browsers capability for multiple classes.

Comment: The IDs on the menu are unique and they're signified in the php with %ID. I'm able to target the correct ID, and i think i can target the correct class with in it as well, but i think its either getting overridden or inheriting from somewhere. i've checked in firebug and chrome and it shows the red text color as striked out, which i presume means that its either overwritten or not applied?

Comment: Crossed out in Firebug means there is another more specific rule that is being applied. Generally the CSS tab (in the HTML) view is ordered from most specific downwards, so should be possible to scroll up to see what other rules have higher precedence.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

```
#dc_jqverticalmegamenu_widget-2 #dc_jqverticalmegamenu_widget-2-item #menu-media-intellectual-property .page-has-children {

}
```

Comment: Tried it. Doesnt seem to make any difference. i really think the css is being overridden, but checking in Firebug and Chrome, i cant figure out which property is overriding it.